# How to display all values in a particular field for multiple parameter values? SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report with two datasets, **DS1** and **DS2**. **DS1** inherits **NameID** from **DS2** and has a field called **"Numbers"** that corresponds to each **NameID**. I have a parameter that displays all the **NameIDs** from **DS2**, and when a **NameID** from the parameter list is select, it displays its corresponding **"Numbers"** field from **DS1** in a table I've created.

The problem arises when I select multiple or "select all" **NameIDs** from the parameter list, where once I select more than one **NameID**, **"Numbers"** doesn't display anything.

**DS1** uses a stored procedure that inherits **NameID** from **DS2** which in turn uses a basic query to grab the NameIDs from a table.

I hope this is enough information or clear enough for anyone who doesn't see the data to understand.

Comment: In the stored proc for DS1 how is the passed in parameter used. Edit he question and show any relevant code that you have

Comment: Multivalue parameters need special handling when used in procedures https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449056/ssrs-multivalue-parameter-stored-procedure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256925/ssrs-multi-value-parameter-using-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a stored procedure, copy the code of the SP to the command text of DS1 and use the parameter there in an IN clause:

```
WHERE NameID IN (@YourParameter)
```